# How to add className to component based on state without removing initial className

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that is toggleable:

```
class HamburgerMenu extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            toggle: false,
        }
    }

    Toggle() {
        this.setState((currentState) => ({
            toggle: !currentState.toggle
        }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <StyledHamburgerMenu className="HamburgerMenu" onClick={ () => this.Toggle() }>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon="bars" />
            </StyledHamburgerMenu>
        )
    }
}
```

and I want to add a class name to a `div` (`extended-right-bar`) jsx element in a separate file:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="grid-display">
        <div className="right-bar">
          <HamburgerMenu /> 
          <PlusButton /> 
        </div>
        <div className="extended-right-bar">
          <h1 className="main-title">Notes</h1>
          <div className="folders-section">
            <h2>Folders</h2>
            <Folder name="folder" />
            <Folder name="folder" />
            <Folder name="folder" />
            <Folder name="folder" />
          </div>
          <div className="tags-section">
            <h2>Tags</h2>
            <Label name="buisness" />
            <Label name="buisness" />
            <Label name="buisness" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="main">
          <NoteWindow />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I do that? They're imported and exported to each other

Comment: Where does that block of code with `extended-right-bar` come in? That is in a different component, right? And how is `HamburgerMenu` related to it?

Comment: The `extended-right-bar` is in my main App.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
element.classList.add("className");
```

to add a class without overwriting the existing ones.

Replace element and className accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can use `redux` to pass `classValue` on toggle to the different component.

```
const Component = (props) => {
    const className = props.classValue ? "extended-right-bar " + props.classValue : "extended-right-bar";

    return (
      <div className={customProps.className}>
        <h1 className="main-title">Notes</h1>
        <div className="folders-section">
          <h2>Folders</h2>
          <Folder name="folder" />
          <Folder name="folder" />
          <Folder name="folder" />
          <Folder name="folder" />
        </div>
      </div>;
    );
}
```